# Spring Batch - Can two different batches share the same Meta-Data datasource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, datasource

I have two different Spring Batch projects, both are configured to have the same datasource (same DB schema) for the Meta-Data tables:

1. *application.properties* (Spring Batch A)

   ```
   spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_batch
   ```
2. *application.properties* (Spring Batch B)

   ```
   spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_batch
   ```

After successfully running Spring Batch A for several times, I ran Spring Batch B and it threw a `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`.

Example:

> org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=2, JobParameters=[{}], Job=[MyBatchName]

During that time, Spring Batch A is no longer running. The exception seems to indicate that the Job Instance ID is already taken by Spring Batch A and cannot be used by Spring Batch B.

Question:

> Can a Spring Batch Meta-Data Schema support multiple Spring Batch projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Micheal Minella, the root cause of the collision was due to the combination of `JOB_NAME` and `JOB_KEY` was not unique.

Definition of `JOB_NAME` and `JOB_KEY`:

> **JOB_NAME:** Name of the job obtained from the `Job` object. Because it is required to identify the instance, it must not be null.
>
> **JOB_KEY:** A serialization of the `JobParameters` that uniquely identifies separate instances of the same job from one another.

`BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` table creation [SQL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-db2.sql)

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    VERSION BIGINT ,
    JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Since my job name is a constant, I need to make sure the `JobParameters` are unique every time I run the batch. As suggested by [Mkyong](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-a-job-instance-already-exists-and-is-complete-for-parameters/), we can add `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a parameter.

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
      .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
```

Comment: On the side note, as I am not using MVC, in order to add `JobParameters`, I have to manually launch the job from my Application class, and set `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to avoid the job running twice.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25185150/5366727

Answer (score 5):

They can but you need to make sure things are unique across jobs.  Specifically the job name and identifying parameters must be unique.  So if JobA and JobB both have the same name, you'll run into collisions.

Comment: It should throw  exception A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={}

Answer (score 1):

`if (status.isRunning() || status == BatchStatus.STOPPING)`  for your job then batch will throw `JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException`.Can you please check in meta data table what is the status of the job or job step.

Once if possible you can  re-create meta data table and check.